# Pedir e armazenar permissão do usuário para usar full-screen?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, fullscreen

Apps geralmente pede permissão para usar recursos do Smartphone como microfone, câmera... Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o mesmo em uma página para que o modo FullScreen seja ativado automaticamente sempre que o usuário abrir a página, uma vez que o mesmo deu permissão para a página.

O código abaixo coloca todo o documento em FullScreen ao ser acionado por algum evento de click por exmeplo:

```
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
```

Existe alguma forma de solicitar a permissão do usuário para que meu site possa usar tal função automaticamente, sem depender de um gatilho dado pelo mesmo?

Comment: Você conhece o conceito de Progressive Web Apps? Acho que é isso que você quer: https://brasil.uxdesign.cc/o-que-s%C3%A3o-progressive-web-apps-86e1b5306051#.8rt2qxssj

Comment: @cav_dan conheço sim, inclusive farei tutoriais no meu site ensinando os usuários sobre, mas não é necessariamente o que eu quero fazer

Answer (score 2):

Bem, você pode criar um link que aponta para uma janela em modo FullScreen da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '', 
'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');">Abrir Janela em Full Screen</a>
```

Se você tentar fazer o mesmo de maneira automática, no onload, é capaz de receber um "bloqueio de popup" do navegador que impede a abertura da janela automaticamente:

```
<body onLoad="window.open('http://www.google.com', '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto'); window.opener=null; window.close(); return false;">
```

A partir do Chrome 15, há a possibilidade de usar a API de Full Screen que abre a tela inteira (e não uma janela) em Full Screen. Vide o [demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html).

Porém não é possível fazê-lo sem interação do usuário, para evitar **usos maliciosos**. Ou seja, o usuário precisa clicar ou apertar uma tecla para invocar o modo de tela cheia.

Acho difícil conseguir contornar esta restrição, pois é algo inerente à especificação do HTML 5.

Vide também esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode).

Comment: Rafael, a primeiro solução através do window.open funciona em todos os navegadores sem bloqueios?

Comment: Não sei te informar, apenas de maneira empírica: no Firefox 52.0 no Ubuntu abriu tanto via link (onClick) como via automático (onLoad); no Chrome 50.0 apenas com o onClick, pois no onLoad bloqueou o PopUp (exigindo confirmação de que é um site confiável).

Comment: Não funcionou muito bem para Chrome que seria minha prioridade, eu uso a API de Full Screen atualmente, e faço a chamada através do primeiro click no documento, mas não acho muito "bonito" fazer isso

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente por motivos de segurança, **especificamente** o `chrome` desabilita a automação do modo `fullscreen`, precisa de uma permissão prévia do usuário para ativá-lo.
Eu utilizei este código para acionar o modo `fullscreen`

```
function requestFullScreen(element) {
// Supports most browsers and their versions.
var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

 if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(element);
 }else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    if (wscript !== null) {
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
 }
}
```

Eu fiz testes colocando o seguinte código nas funções `document.onload`, `document.ready`.

```
 var elem = document.body; 
 requestFullScreen(elem);
```

Obtive a seguinte resposta do navegador no console:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
>   requestFullScreen @ main.html:20

Fontes:
[How to open a web page automatically in full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode)

[Chrome fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api)
[Run a website in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281986/run-a-website-in-fullscreen-mode)